# What is a good way to find which union the variable belongs to?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been trying to create a function where the function's parameter is a union made from two other unions. I want it so that depending on the string passed into the parameter, a different function fires accordingly. Something like this:

```
type Type1 = "a" | "b" | "c";
type Type2 = "x" | "y" | "z";

function doSomething(param: Type1 | Type2) {
    // if param is a part of the "Type1" union
         functionForTypeOne();
}

doSomething("z");
```

I searched through the internet and the docs and I couldn't find a way to do this runtime type checking. I found some "solutions" for type checking, but they were all written for object types, not strings and unions.

In basic javascript, I could create a const array and check if the string is found inside the array, like so:

```
const type1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const type2 = ["x", "y", "z"];

function doSomething(param) {
    if (type1.includes(param))
        functionForTypeOne();
}
```

Doing this in TypeScript *is* kind of a solution, but since I need to create unions from these consts, it feels very inefficient, and doesn't allow me to use the type checking features of the language. I was curious if anyone has a solution for this that I possibly overlooked, or if this is the only way for me to get around my problem.

Comment: you have the right idea https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the unions from your tuples almost automatically, and use a type guard predicate to recover type safety:

```
const type1 = ["a", "b", "c"] as const; // Assert as const to infer tuple instead of array string[]
const type2 = ["x", "y", "z"] as const;

// Automatically get union type from tuple values
type Type1 = typeof type1[number];
//   ^? "a" | "b" | "c"
type Type2 = typeof type2[number];
//   ^? "x" | "y" | "z"

// Type guard predicate
function isIn<T extends readonly string[]>(val: string, arr: T): val is T[number] {
    return arr.includes(val);
}

function doSomething(param: Type1 | Type2) {
    param
    //^? "a" | "b" | "c" | "x" | "y" | "z"
    if (isIn(param, type1)) {
        param
        //^? "a" | "b" | "c"
        //functionForTypeOne();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgRhgXhgbQEQENcAaGXAI2NOFwF0Z8IZRIoBuAKGejiWQCZMOXAA9KueGIBeteoy5t27BChgAVXuizLkIAGY8UqbGACuAWzLIATjQ4B6OzCcA9APxLea3gK289B-mNzSxt7Rxd3dl0TMGAoAEtwGHiIAEkwAB5VGGRhKGQwABNGK2R8QvAAG3gYaCt4sABzbBoAPgAKADd8SoAuWqh6ppJ8Kyt+1QBKfu7K5MZVIItrOgBvdicnUqgTKzB6MYA6BuBKk0LkCC6eyY4AX0Vo2ISkioBlEDNkKAALBsb2ohRvgzBMNDAAD5eFB8SYwdabGBAqwgjabBxuNFOeL6dopdKA4FmEjaVCTOEIxGbZGoqnouyYulOBxPOKJMAAMRAVnUKAA8mBkO1bliYA8HkA)

Comment: I was using a similar solution but without the "isIn" function that you provided. Thanks for your help!